# Get MS Project Title (Not Name)

Tags: vba, ms-project

I need to get the **Title of a project** rather than the name of it. This can be done using the **ProjectSummaryInfoEx** method for the application object  but I'm not sure how to get this line to return the value I need. Without any commands, it simply opens up the Summary info dialog box, and any inputs I provide come back as an invalid argument.

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using:

```
ActiveProject.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Title")
```

or a property of the Project object such as:

```
ActiveProject.Name
```

References: [Application object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.assignment), [Project object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project), [BuiltinDocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.builtindocumentproperties)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. Seems like another good think to add to my arsenal as well.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Rachel's answers, you can also use this:

```
ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(0).Name
```

UID zero will always be the project summary task, and the name property will be the title of the project.